# Inserting pictures crash excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have a loop code that insert pictures in column A cells. However i can't handle the problem when there is no picture in directory. If no picture my macro crash all excels end quit the program.

If i delete error handlers i get a run-time error "1004" about inserting class pictures.

I have a on error resume next line but it's not helping i also made a if ppath(pictures path) <> "" then go ahead. I though that it helped but no.

```
Sub insert_foto()

Dim i As Long
Dim ppath As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RS")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        ws.Range("A6:A" & lastrow).RowHeight = 90
    End With

On Error Resume Next

For i = 6 To lastrow

    'photo in column A
    ppath = "http://aa/bb/" & CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value & "-F1.jpg")
   If ppath <> "" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ppath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 85
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Left + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Width - .Width) / 2
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Top + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Height - .Height) / 2
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
   End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` - that's not an error handler, it just prevents that you see any error (but it happens anyhow). If there is an error, investigate where it comes from and how to prevent it.

Comment: I though that On Error Resume Next will skip the picture that not exist in path and will go to the next picture but that not happen. The error exist in ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ppath) line.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a file exists using "Dir".
If it returns an empty string, it doesn't exist.
So I would do this:

```
If ppath <> "" and Dir(ppath) <> "" Then
```

If it crashes even if the file exists, you might want to count the number of pictures on the sheet before inserting and try inserting a new one until the number of pictures is higher than it was. (Doevents helps you escape from the code in case insert won't work after many attempts.)

```
NrOfPicsBeforeInsert = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count

On Error Resume Next

Do While NrOfPicsBeforeInsert = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ppath
    DoEvents
Loop

On Error GoTo 0
```

This approach might require referring to the last picture added in another way:

```
With ActiveSheet.Pictures(ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count)
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 85
    End With
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Left + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Width - .Width) / 2
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Top + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Height - .Height) / 2
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

Comment: You won't need the first condition actually as ppath is never going to be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its still crashing the excel.

Answer (score 0):

The `On Error Resume Next` is a rather stupid command. It will force the `VBA` runtime to continue with the next statement if something fails. You should use it only if

- you know what you are doing (you know that a specific statement can
  fail),
- you handle the failure by yourself
- you limit the scope to only the single statement that may fail by issuing the statement `On Error Goto 0` which activates the regular VBA error handling.

Else you will hide all runtime errors and at the end you are surprised why your program is not working and have no clue what is going on.

In the following code, I limit the scope to the statement where the image is inserted to the worksheet and check if it was successfull. If not, my variable will be `Nothing` and I know that something failed.

Usually, when dealing with files, you can check the existence of it with the `Dir`-command, but in your case, you want to read the images using `http` and that doesn't work with `Dir`. Anyhow, no matter where the image comes from, there might be other reasons than *file not found* why an image coundn't be loaded (access rights, file is not an valid image...).

There is another issue with your code. You are declaring a worksheet variable `ws` (which is good) but you don't use it (that's not good). You shouldn't work with `ActiveSheet` - that often leads to errors, and it is not necessary that the sheet is *active*. I have added the use of the variable `ws`. Often, rather than writing something like `ws.Cells`, a `With`-statement is used (in that case, you can write `.Cells`, but don't forget the leading dot!), but in this example we have already 2 nested `With` and introducing another one will lead to confusion.

So here is the code. As you see, I store the result of the `Insert` in an intermediate variable and check if it is set.

```
For row = 6 To lastrow
    Dim ppath As String
    'photo in column A
    ppath = "http://aa/bb/" & CStr(ws.Cells(row, 2).Value & "-F1.jpg")

    If ppath <> "" Then
        Dim pic As Picture
        On Error Resume Next                   ' The next statement may fail
        Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(ppath)    ' Try to insert image
        On Error GoTo 0                        ' Back to default error handling

        If pic Is Nothing Then
            ws.Cells(row, 1) = "Could not load " & ppath

        Else
            With pic
                With .ShapeRange
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .Width = 50
                    .Height = 85
                    .Left = ws.Cells(row, 1).Left + (ws.Cells(row, 1).Width - .Width) / 2
                    .Top = ws.Cells(row, 1).Top + (ws.Cells(row, 1).Height - .Height) / 2
                End With
                .PrintObject = True
                .Placement = 1
            End With
            Set pic = Nothing
        End If

   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i couldn't make your code to work. But somehow i managed the problem (I hope) i deleted the on error resume next and made error handler before ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ppath) and placed it just in loop finish before next. Seems to work but have no clue what is the difference between my original code.